# VBA Excel, if value less than

Tags: excel, vba

I have values set to General format in Column C And D. How can a VBA macro change the format to Number wherever the cell value is between 0 and 9 in Column C and D? Basically I want 0 as 0.00 and 9 as 9.00.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub formatit()
    Dim r As Range, N As Long
    Set r = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("C:D"))
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To N
        cc = Cells(i, "C").Value
        dd = Cells(i, "D").Value
        If cc >= 0 And cc <= 9 And dd >= 0 And dd <= 9 Then
            Range(Cells(i, "C"), Cells(i, "D")).NumberFormat = "0.00"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific need for VBA? Otherwise [conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Quick-start-Apply-conditional-formatting-6b6f7c2a-5d62-45a1-8f67-584a76776d67) should help you get there.

- First change *all* fomatting to the 0,00 formatting type (click CTRL+1, choose 'number').
- Next, select all relevant cells, enable conditional formatting: 'format only cells that contain' -> cell values between 0,001 and 8,999 -> set the format to 'general'.

[image]

Comment: I am using a couple of macros to carry out different tasks on every sheet and I want this as an addition to to what is being done already.